# Assign Value of NSNumber to AnyObject

Tags: swift

I have a segment of code that gets info from an API, and I need to add it to a Dictionary. The code is below:

```
 typealias JSONdic = [String: AnyObject]

 var weatherData: AnyObject = StorageManager.getValue(StorageManager.StorageKeys.WeatherData)!
 let json: AnyObject = ["Any": "Object"]
 if let json = json as? JSONdic, history = json["history"] as? JSONdic, tempi = history["tempi"] as? Int, hum = history["hum"] as? String, precip = history["precipi"] as? String{
    println("Temperature:\(tempi) Humidity:\(hum) Precipitation:\(precip)")
    weatherData = [NSDate: AnyObject]()
    let temp = tempi as NSNumber
    weatherData[(The Current Date)] = temp
}
```

I want to first add "temp" to the weatherData Dictionary, but even after casting it to NSNumber, I am told that an NSNumber value cannot be assigned to the AnyObject?! type. Can anyone help me fix this?

Comment: Are you defining weatherData with `let` or `var`?

Comment: weatherData is defined as a variable.

Comment: Your description of the error doesn't seem to match the code you've shown. The code above implies `weatherData` is of type `[NSDate: AnyObject]`, but the error implies it is a dictionary whose values are of type `AnyObject?!`. What does it say when you alt-click on the `weatherData` variable?

Comment: When I Alt-Click on the weatherData variable, it just highlights where it is defined. Also, I've added the initial definition of weatherData. If you need more info I will post the whole class.

Comment: I think you're command-clicking, not alt-clicking (unless you've tweaked the default key bindings?)

Comment: Oh, wait, you're right. I'm used to Windows layouts, and I'm just using a Mac for this project. It tells me that weatherData is of type "AnyObject".

Comment: Ok, I thought as much. See my answer below.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your `weatherData` variable is of type `AnyObject`. Despite the fact that you later assign it a value of type `[NSDate: AnyObject]`, the variable itself is still considered by the compiler to be `AnyObject`. You then hit problems because you try to subscript it, assigning an `NSNumber`, which is obviously not possible on `AnyObject`.

Your declaration of `weatherData` should ensure it is the type you intend. If you are sure that your `StorageManager` will return you the appropriate dictionary type for the weather data key, you can force downcast it to the correct type:

```
var weatherData = StorageManager.getValue(StorageManager.StorageKeys.WeatherData) as! [NSDate: NSObject]
```

Comment: The problem is fixed; it should have been NSObject instead of AnyObject.

Comment: You cannot subscript `NSObject` either. If you want to treat your `weatherData` as a dictionary, it needs to be of type `Dictionary`.

Comment: What I mean is, inside the Dictionary definition, instead of [NSDate: AnyObject], it is [NSDate: NSObject]. Also, instead of **var weatherData: AnyObject = ..._**, it reads **var weatherData: [NSDate: NSObject] = ...** .

Comment: Ok, sounds good! Glad you got it sorted. You can still store `NSNumber` as `AnyObject`, however it might have required casting to prevent a compiler warning/error. Choosing `NSObject` as the value type, as you have done now, is a better idea - I've changed this in the answer as well.